# Possible bug in STD C quicksort. Am i missing something ?

Tags: c

xorshift init: 7731

A:
 2064221648
 1036493097
  633233112
  583013546
  721278080
-1646392714
 -829660162
  478401127

E:
  583013546
  633233112
  721278080
 1036493097
 2064221648
-1646392714
 -829660162
  478401127

Expected:
-1646392714
-829660162
478401127
583013546
633233112
721278080
1036493097
2064221648

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define debug (0 || (sz < 50))

int cmpfunc(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    int x = *(int*)a;
    int y = *(int*)b;
    return x-y;
}

unsigned int xorshift32(unsigned int x)
{
    /* Algorithm "xor" from p. 4 of Marsaglia, "Xorshift RNGs" */
    x ^= x << 13;
    x ^= x >> 17;
    x ^= x << 5;
    return x;
}

int
main()
{
    #define sz 8

    int* a = (int*)malloc(4*sz);

    srand(time(NULL));
    unsigned int init = rand();   printf("xorshift init: %lld\n",init);

    int z=0;
    for(int i = sz-1; i>=0;i+=0)
    {
        a[z] = xorshift32(init) % 0xD0000000U; init = a[z];

        z++;
        i--;
    }
    if(debug)
    {
        printf("A:\n");
        for(int i = 0; i<sz;i++)
        {
            printf("%11d\n", a[i]);
        }printf("\n");
    }

    qsort(a,sz,4,cmpfunc);

    printf("E: \n");
    if(debug)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<sz;i++)
        {
            printf("%11d\n", a[i]);
        }printf("\n");
    }
}
```

win7_x64 | gcc.exe (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0

No optimization or other kind of flags used.

Comment: `"xorshift init: %lld\n"` (note `%LLD`) -> `"xorshift init: %11d\n"`

Comment: You'll have an easier time debugging things if you use the same random seed every time (rather than `time(NULL)`).

Comment: On the whole, if you have some code you wrote, and a standard library function used by millions of programs over many years, and the combination of the two produces odd results, you're usually much better advised to look for the bug in your own code.

Comment: `for(int i = sz-1; i>=0;i+=0) { a[z] = ...; z++; i--; }` This looks suspicious, why not a simple `for(int z = 0; z < sz; z++) { a[z] = ...; }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiled with

```
gcc sort.c -Wall -Wextra
```

There was one error about not matching conversion specifier (`unsigned int` requires `%u` but you had `%lld` - possibly typo for `%11d` but even then it were wrong.

Running, I get sometimes correct output, sometimes not. So I compiled with `-fsanitize=undefined`, and

```
sort.c:11:13: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 
    1288106901 - -1003011281 cannot be represented in type 'int'
E: 
  290879035
  591885416
  767444883
 1288106901
 1955087149
-1509681722
-1289472872
-1003011281
```

I.e. your smart code wasn't too smart there. The correct way to return a value from the comparison function would be

```
return x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0;
```

or

```
return (x > y) - (x < y);
```

as [suggested by HolyBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53821538/possible-bug-in-std-c-quicksort-am-i-missing-something/53821630?noredirect=1#comment94491824_53821630)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat hmm indeed, godbolt shows that mine causes a branch be generated with GCC while yours doesn't.

Comment: Or just `return x < y ? -1 : x > y;`. `... ? 1 : 0` is almost always redundant.

Comment: @rici indeed, I just made it more explicit. Still, GCC will generate that one branch for that too :/

Comment: @antti: unless you ask to optimise or something radical like that. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YiDRha

Comment: Well, that's wild. It's branch free in clang and in gcc6.3. Maybe they know something we don't know.

Comment: Actually the compare code was taken from here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284185) which i thought was solid. I guess i have to learn more about gcc's debuging features before rushing to post.

Comment: @frantzelasg: thanks for the report.That answer should have been flagged as problematic; I added a comment. But it does underline the fact that free advice is worth what you pay for it.

Comment: @FrantzelasG you've fallen victim to "million flies" here :D Had you read all answers carefully, you'd seen [the one by AnT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27284248/918959).

Comment: Indeed. Now that i know what i'm looking for i can appreciate the value of less voted answers. Also [cpp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort) includes  //  return arg1 - arg2; // erroneous shortcut (fails if INT_MIN is present) and the alt. idea is pretty simple we need to extract 2bits of info and map it to 1,0,-1 (x>y) - (x<y) yet my brain couldn't spot the overflow in (x-y) which worked fined most of the time, which also had the blessings of google & community. Lesson learned, use the reference first despite swarm intelligence pointing otherwise.

Comment: @FrantzelasG btw, the correct page would be https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort ;) It too has that info.

Comment: @FrantzelasG you might consider accepting my answer ;)