# Using qsort() inside of struct with array of structs does not access the right elements but 0

Tags: c, struct, qsort

I have the following 2 structs:

```
typedef struct {
  char fullName[40];
  int yearOfBirth;
} Ancestor;

typedef struct {
  Ancestor **ancestor;
  int capacity;
  int size;
} AncestorList;
```

and I would like to sort the `Ancestor` elements os the array by `yearOfBirth`. Here is how I call qsort():

```
qsort(listOfGreatUncles->ancestor, listOfGreatUncles->size, sizeof(Ancestor), compare); //listOfGreatUncles is a AncestorList struct
```

and here is my `compare` procedure:

```
int compare(const void *s1, const void *s2) {
  Ancestor *a1 = (Ancestor *)s1;
  Ancestor *a2 = (Ancestor *)s2;

  printf("a1 yearOfBirth %d\n", a1->yearOfBirth);
  printf("a2 yearOfBirth %d\n", a2->yearOfBirth);

  return (a1->yearOfBirth - a2->yearOfBirth);
  }
}
```

Now my output for a1 and a2 are 0. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements in the array are of type `Ancestor *` and that's what you should use as the operand to `sizeof`. The pointers given to the comparison function are pointers to the **element type** cast to `void *`, hence you cast them back to `Ancestor **` and dereference.

```
qsort(listOfGreatUncles->ancestor, listOfGreatUncles->size, sizeof (Ancestor *), compare);
```

or the form that *always* gives the right size if the array itself is properly typed:

```
qsort(listOfGreatUncles->ancestor, 
      listOfGreatUncles->size, 
      sizeof listOfGreatUncles->ancestor[0],
      compare);
```

i.e.

```
qsort(array, length, sizeof array[0], compfunc);
```

And finally

```
int compare(const void *s1, const void *s2) {
    Ancestor *a1 = *(Ancestor **)s1;
    Ancestor *a2 = *(Ancestor **)s2;

    printf("a1 yearOfBirth %d\n", a1->yearOfBirth);
    printf("a2 yearOfBirth %d\n", a2->yearOfBirth);

    return (a1->yearOfBirth - a2->yearOfBirth);
}
```

And the return value should actually be

```
return (a1->yearOfBirth > a2->yearOfBirth) - (a1->yearOfBirth < a2->yearOfBirth);
```

to avoid [undefined behaviour on extreme values of `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53821538/918959).

Comment: `a1->yearOfBirth - a2->yearOfBirth` may overflow and provide the wrong answer and is UB.  `return (a1->yearOfBirth > a2->yearOfBirth) - (a1->yearOfBirth < a2->yearOfBirth);` nicely handles that.  Of course extreme  _years_ are not expected, such values may occur as sentinels.