# understanding how cmp (comparator functions) is used as arguments to another function

Tags: c#, c

This has been confusing me for sometime, not sure if someone can understand what I am trying to drive at

Source:
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/algorithms-in-a/9780596516246/ch04s06.html

I am trying to figure out what exactly does passing cmp as the argument into buildHeap does

```
buildHeap (ar, cmp, n);
```

the book appears to describe cmp as the comparator function ([How does the compare function in qsort work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284185/how-does-the-compare-function-in-qsort-work)) and given that

```
static void buildHeap (void **ar, int(*cmp)(const void *,const void *), int n) {
```

Am i right to say that

```
int(*cmp)(const void *,const void *)
```

is essentially the C equivalent to a delegate in c#?

i.e. passing cmp into buildHeap teaches buildHeap on what function to implement, being the comparator function (which fits the signature of:)

```
int(*cmp)(const void *,const void *)
```

Would there be another way for me to teach buildHeap to do a comparator function without passing cmp?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Comment: Thank you, the bulk of the question was answered there.

Other than the final question I think?

Comment: Yes, this is same as C# delegate. Func<> in this case.
This comparator function returns int as result and takes two const void * pointers as parameters.

Comment: For the last question, passing the function is maybe the best option. You could also pass an `int` or `char *` and parse it to know the type and then compare them proper.

Comment: Thanks guys. very swift help .. really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cmp` parameter to `buildHeap` is a **function pointer** which points to a function with two `const void *` parameters that returns an int.  `buildHeap` can use this function pointer to call the function in question to compare two items.

For example, if you wanted to compare two integers, you would implement a function like this:

```
int compare_int(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    const int *a = p1;
    const int *b = p2;

    if (*a > *b) {
        return -1;
    } else if (*a < *b) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then you would pass `compare_int` as the second parameter to `buildHeap`, i.e. `buildHeap(arr, compare_int, n)`.  Then somewhere in `buildHeap` it can call this function as appropriate:

```
void buildHeap (void **ar, int(*cmp)(const void *,const void *), int n) {    
   ...
   cmp(ar[x], ar[y]);
   ...
}
```

And calling `cmp` inside of `buildHeap` actually calls `compare_int`.

Comment: thanks.. as i guessed. appreciate u took the time to break it down.

Comment: @youcantcme Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.