# Interpretation of a pointer variable declaration

Tags: c, pointers, declaration, function-declaration

1. What does `int *(cmp)(char*, char*);` mean?
2. What is the difference between  `char* ptr1;` and `char *ptr2;`

Comment: 1) [see here](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+*%28cmp%29%28char*%2C+char*%29%3B) 2) just writing style.

Comment: 1. `int *(cmp)(char*, char*);` is simply `int *cmp(char*, char*);`: `cmp` is a function that takes two arguments and both of type `char *` and returns a pointer to `int`.   

2. No difference. It's matter of choice.

Comment: In the second I prefer `char *ptr2;` because in `char* ptr2, ptr3;` the `ptr3` is not a pointer, it is `char ptr3;`

Comment: Since it's called `cmp` (compare?), I'd be inclined to think the signature is actually `int (*cmp)(char*, char*);`, i.e. a pointer to a function which returns an `int`, as a parameter for a  `qsort`-style *comparison* function (as [explained here](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*cmp%29%28char*%2C+char*%29%3B)). [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27284185/69809) might be useful if you want to see how to write such a function.

Comment: @WeatherVane Simply don't write multiple declarations on a single line - doing so is a well-known safety hazard. Not just for pointers; I've also seen things like `int a,b,c = 0;` when the programmer meant to set all items to zero, not just `c`.

Comment: @Groo Good remark, though in that case it should have been `int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this

```
int *(cmp)(char*, char*);
```

is a declaration of a function that has the return type `int *` and two parameters of the type `char *`.

You may enclose a declarator in parentheses. So the above function declaration can be also rewritten like

```
int * ( (cmp)(char*, char*) );
```

The both declarations are equivalent to

```
int * cmp(char*, char*);
```

A declaration of a pointer to such a function will look like

```
int * ( *p_cmp )(char*, char*) = cmp;
```

There is no difference between these declarations

```
char* ptr1;

char *ptr1;

char * ptr1;
```